# Can an iPhone 5 run 64 bit app?

Tags: ios, iphone, iphone-64bit

I have heard that iOS 11 will support only 64 bit apps.

But I don't quite understand because my iPhone 5 does not have a 64 bit cpu so how will it work?

If an iPhone5 can't run 64 bit apps, and Apple say they will refuse new 32 bit app in the app store starting in January 2018, how can I continue to maintain my app for my iPhone 5 users after 2018 ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The iPhone 5S has an [A7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_A7) chip. This is a 64 bit CPU, which is why it can run iOS 11.  An iPhone 5, however, cannot be upgraded past iOS 10.

You will still be able to submit apps containing both 32 bit and 64 bit slices and, so as long as the minimum iOS requirement of your app is < iOS 11 the app will still run on an iPhone 5

You can no longer submit 32 bit only binaries.  Older, 32 bit only, apps give a warning in iOS 10 and will not run in iOS 11.

After January 2018 you cannot submit a 32 bit app to the **mac app store**

Comment: and what about the iphone 5 ? i made a mistake i have an iphone 5 :(

Comment: The iPhone 5 cannot be upgraded beyond iOS 10

Comment: in this way how can we still maintain our app on iphone 5 after 2018 ?

Comment: As I said, you can still submit apps containing both 32 bit and 64 bit slices, so as long as the minimum iOS requirement of your app is <iOS 11 the app will still run on an iPhone 5

Comment: so you mean after 2018 i can still submit app containing both 32 bit and 64 bit slide ? i heard it's not possible as apple accept only 64 bit after 2018

Comment: Where did you see that?

Comment: on forum, dev say me this, this why i ask confirmation here :)

Comment: I think you are getting confused with the Mac app store - ["Starting in January of 2018, all new apps submitted to the Mac App Store must be 64-bit"](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/06/06/apple-to-phase-out-32-bit-mac-apps/)

Comment: OK, so to confirm and accept your answer: after 2018 we can no longer submit 32bit app only but we can still submit 32bit + 64 bit app right ?

Comment: I actually don't think it has been possible to submit 32 bit only apps to the iOS app store for about 2 years.  32bit apps that haven't been updated to include a 64 bit slice will no longer work under iOS 11